# c# Multiple generic constraints on return type (similar to Java)

Tags: c#, generics, return-type

I'd like to write code similar to this:

```
public IEnumerable<TSystem> GetSystems<T>() where TSystem : T
{
    _systems.Where(system => system is T).Cast<TSystem>();
}
```

But I'm getting the error
`'GetSystems<T>()': A constraint references nonexistent type parameter 'TSystem' (CS0699)`.

I think something similar would be possible in java using `&`:

```
public IEnumerable<System & T> GetSystems<T>() { ... }
```

If I include the generic constraint in the type parameters of the method, I would have to specify a specific type which implements `T` instead of working for all types which implement it.

As for why, it would be nice to be able to treat the returned IEnumerable as both an `IEnumerable<System>` as well as `IEnumerable<T>` without casting.

```
GetSystems<ISomeInterface>().SomeSystemExtensionMethod(
    system => system.SomeInterfaceMethod());

public static void SomeSystemExtenstionMethod(
    this IEnumerable<System>, Action<System> action) { ... }
```

Is this possible in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Use this declaration instead

```
public IEnumerable<TSystem> GetSystems<T, TSystem>() where TSystem : T
```

In C# all the generic type parameters for either input or output types must be included in between < .. >

Comment: Then it can only work with a specific type that implements T, not just any. (As I already mentioned above.)

Comment: Yes, that should satisfy the requirement

Comment: Say I had two system classes `ASystem` and `BSystem`, both implemented interface `ISomeInterface`. My hypothetical function should return an IEnumerable that included instances of both classes that implement this interface, without having to cast to `System` or `ISomeInterface`. Your suggestion would only be able to return either `ASystems`s or `BSystem`s.